# C# library to read PPTX files

Tags: gratis, software-development, offline

I'm looking for a library that can read Microsoft Powerpoint files.

- it must support the PPTX file format
- PPT is not required
- it does not need Office installed
- hopefully it's easy to use, not like Office Interop
- it's gratis, also for commercial use
- can be used in .NET 4
- writing files would be awesome, but reading only is ok for now

I'm looking for something similar like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) for Excel files or [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX) for Word files.

[Gembox.Presentation](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/presentation/pricelist) might do the job, but is far too expensive.

Answer (score 4):

Check out SyncFusion's [DocIO](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/overview) and specifically  https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/presentation

There is a community edition that you may qualify for (has a generous upper limit if you are a commercial enterprise) that is free.

Comment: Nice finding. Indeed my company would be eligible.